# Word filter with PHP

Tags: php, forms, function, magento, filter

I'm trying to create a word filter in my Magento site, basically I have a form with a textarea and a submit button as follow:

```
<form id="answer_form_<?php echo $id;?>" class="form" method="post" 
action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('productquestions/productquestions/saveanswers',array('product_questions_id'=>$id));?>">

<textarea id="txt_send" class="input-text required-entry " name="content" 
id="answer_content_<?php echo $id;?>" title="Content"></textarea>

<button id="btn_send" style="float: left;" type="submit" class="button" 
title="Send Message"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Send Message') ?></span></span></button>

</form>
```

What I need to do is to filter the words from the textarea when the form is submitted **before** it's saved on the database, so I founded some php functions and adapted it. The final code is:

```
function wordFilter($text) {       
   $filter_terms = array('\bass(es|holes?)?\b','\bshit(e|ted|ting|ty|head)\b');
   $filtered_text = $text;

   foreach($filter_terms as $word) {
      $match_count = preg_match_all('/' . $word . '/i', $text, $matches);

      for($i = 0; $i < $match_count; $i++) {
         $bwstr = trim($matches[0][$i]);
         $filtered_text = preg_replace('/\b' . $bwstr . '\b/', str_repeat("*", strlen($bwstr)), $filtered_text);
     }

   }
   return $filtered_text;
}

if(isset($_POST['btn_send'])) {
   $text = htmlentities($_POST['txt_send']);

   $text = wordFilter($text);
}
```

I just added two words for test so far, and when I do the text with both words it's saved normally without changing them to "*****". I avoided using JS since it's client side.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks!

EDITED:

As a Magento plugin. The action redirect the form to:
`productquestions/productquestions/saveanswers',array('product_questions_id'=>$id));` and depending on the id it changes the url. As example: `siteurl/index.php/productquestions/productquestions/saveanswers/product_questions_id/40`
in this controller page I have the function:

```
public function saveanswersAction() 
    {
        $answers = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $answerCollection = array();
        $model = Mage::getModel('productquestions/answers'); 
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_questions_id');

        $model->setData('product_questions_id',$id);
        $model->setData('answers',$answers['content']);

        $model->save();
        $answerCollection[] = $model;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to be sure as you don't include the code where this is doing the save but it looks like you are not saving the result of your filter function back in to the variable that gets saved.
Try:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_send'])) {
    $text = htmlentities($_POST['txt_send']);
    $text = wordFilter($text);
    //Code to save $text here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just moved the code to the controller and it worked, thank for the tip.

```
$text = $this->getRequest()->getParam('content');
        $filter_terms = array('\bass(es|holes?)?\b','\bshit(e|ted|ting|ty|head)\b');
        $filtered_text = $text;
        foreach($filter_terms as $word)
        {
             $match_count = preg_match_all('/' . $word . '/i', $text, $matches);
             for($i = 0; $i < $match_count; $i++)
             {
                   $bwstr = trim($matches[0][$i]);
                   $filtered_text = preg_replace('/\b' . $bwstr . '\b/', str_repeat("*", strlen($bwstr)), $filtered_text);
             }
        }

$model->setData('answers',$filtered_text);
```